# How do you change the color of a binned scatter created by binsreg?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the color of a binned scatter plot that is created with the "binsreg" package. I know how to add lines etc. within a ggplot, but I don't know where I can change things within the "bins_plot". Below, you see an example. How do I change the color of the points from blue to green, for instance?

```
library(binsreg)
library(ggplot)

x <- rnorm(100,0,1)
err <- rnorm(100,0,0.5)
y <- x + err

data <- data.frame(x,y)

a <- binsreg(y,x, nbins = 15)

a$bins_plot +
  geom_smooth(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), method = "lm")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `bycolors` argument of the `binsreg` function:

```r
library(binsreg)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100,0,1)
err <- rnorm(100,0,0.5)
y <- x + err

data <- data.frame(x,y)

a <- binsreg(y, x, nbins = 15, bycolors = "green")

a$bins_plot +
  geom_smooth(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), method = "lm")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>